# Find or count all usages of an end note in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I have created a document with end notes in it. I have referred to individual end notes multiple times in the document. How can I either find all usages or preferably count all usages of an end note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see if the following VBA gets you anything close to what you need (it would probably need quite a bit of improvement to deal with all possible reference locations, etc., and to present the output better).

```
Sub countEndNoteRefs()
Dim bShowHidden As Boolean
Dim eno As Word.Endnote
Dim fld As Word.Field
Dim lCount As Long
Debug.Print "Note", "Refs", "Text"
For Each eno In ActiveDocument.Endnotes
  bShowHidden = eno.Reference.Bookmarks.ShowHidden
  eno.Reference.Bookmarks.ShowHidden = True
  lCount = 0
  If eno.Reference.Bookmarks.Count > 0 Then
    For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
      If fld.Type = Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldNoteRef Then
        If InStr(1, UCase(fld.Code), UCase(eno.Reference.Bookmarks(1).Name)) > 0 Then
          lCount = lCount + 1
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End If
  eno.Reference.Bookmarks.ShowHidden = bShowHidden
  Debug.Print eno.Index, lCount, eno.Range.Text
Next
End Sub
```